# Failed to insert row into a data frame

Tags: r

I created a dataframe as below:

```
d <- data.frame(Year=character())
```

after that I got a warning message when insert rows into the data frame:

```
> d[0,] <- '100'
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 0, , value = "100") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

I am not sure what the problem with my code. Is the `d[0,]=` not correct?

**EDIT1**

I tried to use 1 as the index but still got an error:

```
> d[1,] <- '100'
```

> Warning message:
>       In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = 100) :
>         invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: You should start it from 1 not 0, `d[1,] <- 100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the excerpts of a book called "**Hands-On Programming with R**" by Garrett Grolemund, I hope quoting a book is allowed in SO.

> In some programming languages, indexing begins with 0. This means that
>   0 returns the first element of a vector, 1 returns the second element,
>   and so on.
>
> This isn’t the case with R. Indexing in R behaves just like indexing
>   in linear algebra. The first element is always indexed by 1.

You should start the indexing from 1 not 0, so in your case it should be

```
d[1,] <- 100

> d
  Year
1  100
```

EDIT: It also seems that OP was using stringsAsFactors=T , in that case he is recieving the a warning as below:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "100") :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

However, if one should do a `stringsAsFactors=F` then we can avoid the above warning

```
d <- data.frame(Year=character(),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

One can also disable this option by using `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` on r console

Thanks

Comment: I have tried to use 1 as the index but still got an error. I have updated my question.